# VBA Matrix Print

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, printing

The code below is supposed to print out a generated Matrix. I can see from the Locals window, that the Matrix is holding values on 202 rows and 4 columns.

**However the last line:**

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine) = Matrix
```

Only prints out the 1st value in the matrix as in (1,1). What am I doing wrong? I've tried a ton of different variables here..

```
Sub MatrixPrint()

Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim arr As Range
Dim rng As Variant, cl As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim Matrix As Variant

With Sheet2
    lr1 = Worksheets("ExampleOne").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set arr = Worksheets("ExampleOne").Range("K2:K" & lr1 + 1)

End With

'Define cash receipt range from which to look from
With Blad16
    lr2 = Worksheets("ExampleTwo").Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    rng = Worksheets("ExampleTwo").Range("F20:F" & lr2)
End With

x = 0
For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
    Set C1 = arr.Find(rng(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If C1 Is Nothing Then
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim rng2 As Range

With Sheet2
    lr1 = Worksheets("ExampleOne").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = Worksheets("ExampleOne").Range("A2:K" & lr1 + 1)
End With

With Blad16
    lr2 = Worksheets("ExampleTwo").Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("ExampleTwo").Range("F20:F" & lr2)
End With


ReDim Matrix(1 To UBound(arr2) - x, 1 To 4)
x = 1

For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2) - 1

        Set c2 = rng2.Find(arr2(i, 11), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If c2 Is Nothing Then
        Matrix(x, 1) = arr2(i, 3)
        Matrix(x, 2) = arr2(i, 4)
        Matrix(x, 3) = arr2(i, 8)
        Matrix(x, 4) = arr2(i, 11)

        x = x + 1
        Else

        End If

Next i

    Debug.Print (x)
   Worksheets("Sheet6").Select
    ExportToLine = 16 
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine) = Matrix

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine)` returns only one cell. Excel will write the intersection of your range and the array. So if you did

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine).Resize(2,2).Value = Matrix
```

Then you would get four values no matter how big Matrix is. What you want is

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C" & ExportToLine).Resize(UBound(Matrix,1), UBound(Matrix,2)).Value = Matrix
```

Comment: Hi thank you, this works! Is it possible to print a single column of the matrix to Column B and then another column to column D for example?

Comment: You should create a new question for that. It's not simple answer that could fit in a comment.